# vb.net как добавить пробелы в один большой String, через каждый N

Tags: .net

У меня есть `List(Of String())` из которого я читаю каждый сохраненный в нем String и добавляю его к обычному `String`. В итоге, чтобы все не было как `HelloHelloHelloHello`, мне нужно разделить их пробелами.

```
Dim l_lsFiles = GroupFiles(l_sExtension, pi_iPicNumer, True)
Dim str As String = ""

For Each l_iPicture As String() In l_lsFiles
  str += String.Join(" ", l_iPicture)
Next l_iPicture

b_composeAppService.Compose_image(New String() {str}, Function(m) m, Function(i) i, False)
```

Грубо говоря, мне нужно создать `String()` или `String` с пробелами и передать его в `Compose_image`

Пробоевал то-то вроде

```
For sss As Integer = 0 To 10
      str += str.Insert(12 * 2, " ")
    Next
```

Comment: `str = String.Join(" ", l_lsFiles)`

Comment: Цикл `For Each` совсем не нужен при этом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вашим методом получаю ошибку `List(Of String())` не может быть конвертирован в `String()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким путем

```
For Each l_iPicture As String() In l_lsFiles
      str += " " + String.Join(" ", l_iPicture)
    Next l_iPicture
```